# Add customer email and phone number in invoice print

Tags: opencart, invoice, opencart-3

I'm using the Opencart 3.0.2.0. How to add customer's email and phone number in the order invoice print?

Please, can anyone give the solution?

Answer (score 2):

To add customer's phone number and email id to customer's order invoice print you need to edit controller, language and view files. which is quit lengthier process.

Instead, you could use this [extension](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=23987&filter_search=invoice&filter_license=0) which has 9invoice templates and includes Customer's Phone Number and email in it.

Hope this answer might help you